# Same HttpURLConnection working on app but fail with FileNotFoundException on Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, httpconnection

This is how I'm connecting from my app to my server:

```
try {

            URL url;
            // get URL content
            url = new URL(apiURL);
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            trustAllHosts();

            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

            conn.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setRequestProperty(MainActivity.API_TOKEN, MainActivity.ENCRYPTED_TOKEN);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            in=conn.getInputStream();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            while ((line=br.readLine())!= null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            result=builder.toString();

            br.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            result=null;
        } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
            result=null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result=null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result=null;
        }
```

This is working like a charm when I'm using it from my app. However using it from a widget got catch by `catch (IOException e)` and send me the following error: `FileNotFound`. My server is actually returning me the error 500, meaning that its encountered a problem.

Is there some requirements when using an asyncTask to connect to a server from a widget? Is there some special parameters or settings I should take care of? Thanks.

Comment: how do you obtain "apiURL"? can you make sure it is 100% the same no matter which component generated it?

Comment: This url is working for sure. I compared this one with the one from the app. Also, trying this apiUrl from a browser works...

Comment: Do you run this code inside the widget's "onUpdate()"? As far as I know, one could start a service (IntentService) to do the download and then update the widget. Inside this IntentService one should not start an AsyncTask because the IntentService would be finished (by the system) as soon as it's stopped executing anything (while waiting for the task to finish). Other possibility: use a RemoteViewsService.

Comment: Running on onUpdate yes. However my widget is supposed to wait for the end of the call and for its result. It seems that the problem could be linked to the IP address, according to my server...

Comment: There is more than one statement which could throw an IOException (at least "openConnection()" and "getInputStream()"). Could you find out which one it is?  -  And I'm wondering whether the call from the widget's process will get another IP address than the call from the regular application process. After all, there could be many apps on one phone requesting internet access and exchanging data with some servers, so there would have to be some kind of "internal IP" to route the data. But I'm afraid that's not my strong point. I'm better at widget-app communication ;-)

Comment: I made a good use of the debugger provided with android studio, which lead me to get this error on the widget only while for some reason the exact same process was working elsewhere... More precisely, "getInputStream()" is the error thrower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96958/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-virthuss).